# is it possible to build full XML webpage just like HTML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I been wondering for some while now. Could you possibly create a web site build with use of XML and XSLT? For a fact I know you can style XML pages with XSLT which is similar to CSS. I seen some sites with .xml extension in the URL, but to my view that seems more like Mod_Rewrite instead of actual .XML file. So could somebody confirm this. Is it possible? Or is it not possible to make XML based web pages just liked you would with HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you can do this. Many people do.

To expand a little, there are three stages at which you can apply the XSLT: at publishing time (in which case you publish HTML on your site, and your users never know it was once XML); at page delivery time on the server, and at page delivery time in the client browser. Relatively few people use client-side XSLT, because it's only recently that it's been available on every browser (and even now, it's often not available on mobile browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use XML data and Velocity templates to generate the page.

I prefer Velocity because the template looks like the end product; not so with XSL-T.

Comment: Huh, interesting. And I always though that you can't do much with XML, well I just learned something new for my self.

Comment: Actually you can use the small subset of XSLT called "simplified stylesheets" in exactly the way you would write a simple Velocity template. But very few people confine themselves to this subset, because using XSLT template rules to the full gives you so much more power and flexibility.

Comment: It's not the rules or the power that are the problem.  Velocity's advantage is that the template looks exactly like the thing that you want to produce.  User interface developers are unlikely to know how XSL-T works, but they know what an HTML page looks like.  It widens the audience that can work with generating dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can style .xml with css as well. However, since there is no default 
styling, you have to be explicit about the css display attribute for each element tag.
You can also use css generated content to add text, and for example, display
`<sometag>text</sometag>`  as  `sometag: text`

However, getting linking semantics to work cross browser is a bit of a problem:

```
link {text-decoration: underline; color: blue; link: attr(href)}
```

for example, will work in some but not all browsers, to make `<link href=URL>`
work like a clickable link. ( Perhaps a javascript solution works more portably. )

But doing xslt conversion to html in the browser with an `<?xml-stylesheet >` directive
seems to work in all modern browsers without problem, and can do a lot more than css alone.

Some examples [here](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=24).